# fastlane get current testflight train

Tags: fastlane

using fastlane's spaceship, i'd like to:

- get the train version of the binary that is live (or nil)
- get the latest train version in testflight... (or nil)

---

- if latest testflight train is nil, then return 0.0.1
- if live train equals latest testflight train, then return (live train + 0.0.1)
- otherwise return the latest testflight train

---

I'm stuck figuring out how to query for the "train version" of the build of the live version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
version = app.live_version
latest_version = version.raw_data["preReleaseBuildTrainVersionString"]
```

Will give you the train version string of the live build